# Split the string with hyphen symbol multiple occurrence using regex /java

Tags: java, regex

Getting the string value using the below xpath

```
String noAndDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='c38']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/strong")).getText();
```

Output of the above string  = `2928554 - 2009-09-18 (BOPI 2009-38)`

my expected output

```
2928554
2009-09-18
```

i tried below split, but i'm not getting my expected output

```
String[] words = noAndDate.split("-");
```

Please advice/help me

Comment: er does `2009-09-18` also have hyphens in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instead try splitting on a regex alternation which looks for a hyphen surrounded by whitespace, or pure whitespace:

```
String input = "2928554 - 2009-09-18 (BOPI 2009-38)";
String[] parts = input.split("(\\s+-\\s+|\\s+)");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code-

String str = "2928554 - 2009-09-18 (BOPI 2009-38)";

String str1 = str.split(" - | ")[0];

String str2 = str.split(" - | ")[1];

This will return str1 as 2928554 and str2 as 2009-09-18.

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score -1):

Just split with regex will do.

```
String given = "2928554 - 2009-09-18 (BOPI 2009-38)";
String [] splitted = given.split(" - |\\s+");
String result = splitted[0] +", "+splitted[1];
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
2928554, 2009-09-18
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

> String[] words = noAndDate.split(" ");

then

> System.out.println(words[0]);
>
> System.out.println(words[2]);

Comment: Your first print statement would be correct, but the second one would print the entire remainder of the string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did not notice the spaces

Comment: I rectified my answer and this one is working as well :-P just split by space

Answer (score -2):

Use Regex capture groups, here you can see what you want in 2 groups:

```
(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)
```

() = group